# Why am I getting "Closing delimiter C not found" error when upgrading from PHP 5 to PHP 7

Tags: regex, preg-replace, php-7, php-5.6

I am using the php7cc tool https://github.com/sstalle/php7cc to help upgrade to PHP7.  It is returning an error that I do not know how to fix because it does not give a line number and I do not exactly know what it wants me to fix.  I get a

```
"text" : "Closing delimiter C not found",
              "line" : null
```

error from the json returned from php7cc.  This is the page that is returning it:

```
<?php
class geo
{
var $postcode = "";
var $lat = 0;
var $lng = 0;

function setPostcode($postcode)
{
    $this->postcode = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", strtoupper(trim($postcode)));
}

function getPostcode()
{
    return $this->postcode;
}

function getLatLong($postcode="")
{
    if($postcode)
        $this->setPostcode($postcode);

    if($this->isValidPostCode())
    {
        if($_SESSION['GEO'][$this->postcode])
            return $_SESSION['GEO'][$this->postcode];

        $url = "http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$this->postcode."&sensor=false&region=uk";
        $jsonData = file_get_contents($url);

        if($jsonData)
        {
            $data = json_decode($jsonData);

            $this->lng = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
            $this->lat = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;

            if($this->lng && $this->lat)
                $result = array("postcode"=>$this->postcode, "lat"=>$this->lat, "lng"=>$this->lng);
            else
                $result = array("error"=>"Postcode doesn't exist");

            $_SESSION['GEO'][$this->postcode] = $result;
            return $_SESSION['GEO'][$this->postcode];
        }
        return array("error", "Unable to fetch lat/long");
    }
    else
    {
        return array("error"=>"Invalid postcode");
    }
}

function isValidPostCode()
{
    // Permitted letters depend upon their position in the postcode.
    $alpha1 = "[abcdefghijklmnoprstuwyz]";                          // Character 1
    $alpha2 = "[abcdefghklmnopqrstuvwxy]";                          // Character 2
    $alpha3 = "[abcdefghjkstuw]";                                   // Character 3
    $alpha4 = "[abehmnprvwxy]";                                     // Character 4
    $alpha5 = "[abdefghjlnpqrstuwxyz]";                             // Character 5

    // Expression for postcodes: AN NAA, ANN NAA, AAN NAA, and AANN NAA
    $pcexp[0] = '^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';

    // Expression for postcodes: ANA NAA
    $pcexp[1] =  '^('.$alpha1.'{1}[0-9]{1}'.$alpha3.'{1})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';

    // Expression for postcodes: AANA NAA
    $pcexp[2] =  '^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'[0-9]{1}'.$alpha4.')([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';

    // Exception for the special postcode GIR 0AA
    $pcexp[3] =  '^(gir)(0aa)$';

    // Standard BFPO numbers
    $pcexp[4] = '^(bfpo)([0-9]{1,4})$';

    // c/o BFPO numbers
    $pcexp[5] = '^(bfpo)(c\/o[0-9]{1,3})$';

    // Load up the string to check, converting into lowercase and removing spaces
    $postcode = strtolower($this->postcode);

    // Assume we are not going to find a valid postcode
    $valid = false;

    // Check the string against the six types of postcodes
    foreach ($pcexp as $regexp)
    {
        if (preg_match($regexp,$postcode, $matches))
        {

          // Load new postcode back into the form element
          $toCheck = strtoupper ($matches[1] . ' ' . $matches [2]);

          // Take account of the special BFPO c/o format
          $toCheck = preg_replace ('C/O', 'c/o ', $toCheck);

          // Remember that we have found that the code is valid and break from loop
          $valid = true;
          break;
        }
    }

    // Return with the reformatted valid postcode in uppercase if the postcode was
    // valid
    if ($valid){return true;} else {return false;};
}
}
?>
```

I did not write this code.  my guess is somthing to do with the `preg_replace ('C/O', 'c/o ', $toCheck);` but I don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to simplify your example to test it.

The only obvious thing I found is your regex strings do not have delimiters, e.g.

```
$pattern="/^([0-9]+)$/";
```

See: [PHP-Delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Plus, in preg_replace there is also an unescaped / if you add the standard delimiters. This is what probably causing the error.

```
<?php

isValidPostCode();

function isValidPostCode()
{
    // Permitted letters depend upon their position in the postcode.
    $alpha1 = "[abcdefghijklmnoprstuwyz]";                          // Character 1
    $alpha2 = "[abcdefghklmnopqrstuvwxy]";                          // Character 2
    $alpha3 = "[abcdefghjkstuw]";                                   // Character 3
    $alpha4 = "[abehmnprvwxy]";                                     // Character 4
    $alpha5 = "[abdefghjlnpqrstuwxyz]";                             // Character 5

    // Expression for postcodes: AN NAA, ANN NAA, AAN NAA, and AANN NAA
    $pcexp[0] = '/^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$/';

    // Expression for postcodes: ANA NAA
    $pcexp[1] =  '/^('.$alpha1.'{1}[0-9]{1}'.$alpha3.'{1})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$/';

    // Expression for postcodes: AANA NAA
    $pcexp[2] =  '/^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'[0-9]{1}'.$alpha4.')([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$/';

    // Exception for the special postcode GIR 0AA
    $pcexp[3] =  '/^(gir)(0aa)$/';

    // Standard BFPO numbers
    $pcexp[4] = '/^(bfpo)([0-9]{1,4})$/';

    // c/o BFPO numbers
    $pcexp[5] = '/^(bfpo)(c\/o[0-9]{1,3})$/';

    // Load up the string to check, converting into lowercase and removing spaces
    $postcode = strtolower("AANN NAA C/0 dks");

    // Assume we are not going to find a valid postcode
    $valid = false;

    // Check the string against the six types of postcodes
    foreach ($pcexp as $regexp)
    {
        if (preg_match($regexp,$postcode, $matches))
        {

          // Load new postcode back into the form element
          $toCheck = strtoupper ($matches[1] . ' ' . $matches [2]);

          // Take account of the special BFPO c/o format
          $toCheck = preg_replace ('/C\/O/', 'c/o ', $toCheck);

          // Remember that we have found that the code is valid and break from loop
          $valid = true;
          break;
        }
    }

    // Return with the reformatted valid postcode in uppercase if the postcode was
    // valid
    if ($valid){return true;} else {return false;};
}
```

Comment: The delimiter is also missing in the `preg_replace` pattern (that can be replaced by a `str_replace`)

Comment: Note that the `{1}` quantifier is always useless, whatever the pattern.

Comment: Thank you, replacing `preg_replace ('C/O', 'c/o ', $toCheck);` with `preg_replace ('/C\/O/', 'c/o ', $toCheck);` removed the error!